# Sufficient and complete statistic: hypergeometrical distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

> How can one show that for a r.v. $X$ that is hypergeometrically distributed, i.e. $X\sim H_{N, A, n} (N, n \text{ fixed})$, $X$ is sufficient and complete for the part $\theta = \frac{A}{N}$.

So the definition of sufficient is that the conditional distribution $X\mid T=t$ is independent of $\theta$. One can show that sufficency is equivalent to

$$f_{\theta}(x) = g(T(x), \theta) h(x).$$

Do I have to use this criterion or is it possible to show it directly? How could I start here?

I guess like that:

\begin{align}
P(X=x) & = \frac{ \binom A x \binom{N-A}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}} =\frac{A! (N-A)! (N-n)!}{(A-x)!(N-A-n+x)!N!} \cdot \frac{n!}{x!(n-x)!} \\[10pt]
& = \frac{A! (N-A)! (N-n)!}{(A-x)! (N-A-n+x)!N!} \binom n x
\end{align}

which is probably almost the factorization required?

The definition of completness is that if $E_{\theta} h(T) = 0 \text{ } \forall \theta \in \Theta$, then $h(t)=0$ a.s.

Do I have to find one specific function to prove this?

Comment: Your data consists of only one observation, $X$. The whole data set is always a sufficient statistic. The conditional distribution of $X$ given $X$ does not depend on $\theta$ since $\Pr(X=x \mid X=x) = 1,$ i.e. it's the distribution that concentrates all of the probability at just one point, and you certainly don't need to know the value of $\theta$ to know that. Since your proposed function $T$ is just the identity function, $T(x)=x,$ the Fisher factorization is trivial: $f_\theta(x) = g_\theta(T(x))\cdot h(x) = f_\theta(x)\cdot 1.$ It remains to show completeness.

Comment: Thank you, that was my first thought as well (the conditional probabilty), but it seemed too easy...and how do I show the completeness?

Comment: $$
\operatorname{E}_\theta(h(X)) = \sum_{x=\max\{0,\,A-N+n\}}^{\min\{A,\,n\}} h(x) \frac{ \binom A x \binom{N-A}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}}.
$$
Do we want to say this is $0$ for all values of $A \in \{ 0,\ldots,N \},$ with $N$ fixed, or for all pairs $(N,A)$, with $N\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $A\in\{ 0, \ldots, N \} \text{?}$ I'd start with the latter alternative and see what happens. $\qquad$

Comment: However, I wonder if $\text{“}N, n \text{ fixed''}$ was supposed to mean BOTH $N$ and $n$ are $\text{“}$fixed$\text{''}$, in which case it might just mean for all values of $A.\qquad$

Comment: Yeah it says that both $N$ and $n$ are fixed. What do I have to do then? I have to show, that is the expectation is $0$, that already $h(x)=0$ right? Which are my limits of the sum then?

Comment: An essential point is that the sum continues to be equal to $0$ if $A$ changes. $\qquad$

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}_\theta(h(X)) & = \sum_{x=\max\{0,\,A-N+n\}}^{\min\{A,\,n\}} h(x) \frac{ \binom A x \binom{N-A}{n-x}}{\binom{N}{n}} \\  \\
& = \frac 1 {\binom N n} \sum_{x=\max\{0, A-N+n\}}^{\min\{A,n\}} h(x) \frac{A!(N-A)!}{x!(A-x)!(n-x)!(N-A-n+x)!} \\
& \,\uparrow \text{ This equality holds because $1/\tbinom N n$ does not change as $x$ changes.} \\  \\
& = \frac{A!(N-A)!}{\binom N n} \sum_{x=\max\{0, A-N+n\}}^{\min\{A,n\}} \frac{h(x)}{x!(A-x)!(n-x)!(N-A-n+x)!} \\
& \, \uparrow \text{ Same reason here: $A!(N-A)!$ does not change as $x$ changes.}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you, so since the expectation is 0, it follows that the sum has to be zero. How can we show now, that each term in the sum is equal to zero (and therefore $h(x)=0$?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
& \text{For every value of } A \text{ in the set } \{0,1,2,\ldots,N\} \text{ we have} \\ \\
& \sum_{x=\max\{0, A-N+n\}}^{\min\{A,n\}} \frac{h(x)}{x!(A-x)!(n-x)!(N-A-n+x)!} = 0.
\end{align}
$$
For each value of $A$ separately, that is a linear equation in the variables $h(m), h(m+1), h(m+2),\ldots, h(\ell)$ where $m =\max\{0, A-N+n\}$ and $\ell= \min\{A,n\}.$ You have to show there are no solutions other than $h(m) = h(m+1) = h(m+2) = \cdots = h(\ell)=0.$ The number of variables is $\ell - m + 1$ and the number equations is $N+1. \qquad$