# Show the class of hypergeometric probability distribution is complete.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

We define the class of hypergeometric probability distribution as $\left\{P_{D}: D=0,1,2, \cdots, N\right\}$, where

$$
P_{D}(X=x)=\frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
D \\
x
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
N-D \\
n-x
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
N \\
n
\end{array}\right)} \quad x=0,1, \cdots, \min (n, D)
$$

Show that it is a complete class.

---

I have seen this answer to the question: [Sufficient and complete statistic: hypergeometrical distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030499/sufficient-and-complete-statistic-hypergeometrical-distribution), but I still can't figure it out.

---

**What I did:**

Our goal is to show that for any population size $N$, if $$\mathbb{E}_D[T(X)]= \sum^{\min(D,n)}_{x=0} T(x) \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
D \\
x
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
N-D \\
n-x
\end{array}\right)}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
N \\
n
  \end{array}\right)} = 0 ,$$
Then $T(x) = 0$ almost everywhere. By expanding the binomial coefficients, this can be reduced to showing that
$$ \sum^{\min(D,n)}_{x=0} \frac{T(x)}{x!(D-x)! (n-x)!(N+x-n-D)!} =0 \iff T(x) = 0 \; \forall x\in [0, \min (D,n)] \quad(*)$$
Now, it seems like the way to go about proving this is to induct on $N$. For the base case, if $N=0$ then $D = 0$ and $n=0$, so

$$ 0= \sum^{\min(D,n)}_{x=0} \frac{T(x)}{x!(D-x)! (n-x)!(N+x-n-D)!} = \frac{T(0)}{0!(0-0)! (0-0)!(0+0-0-0)!}= T(0) $$
For the inductive step, we assume $(*)$ holds up to $N$, and show it also does for $N+1$. So,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
0&= \sum^{\min(D,n)}_{x=0} \frac{T(x)}{x!(D-x)! (n-x)!(N+1+x-n-D)!} \\ 
&= \sum^{\min(D,n)}_{x=0} \frac{T(x)}{x!(D-x)! (n-x)!(N+x-n-D)!} \frac{1}{(N+1+x-n-D)}
  \end{split}
\end{equation}

This is where I get stuck. How do I deal with $\min(n, D)$? Where do I use the induction hypothesis? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Completeness is the property of a statistic relative to a specific parameter. Saying that the "hypergeometric probability distribution is complete" is a meaningless statement in that case. What is the statistic you wish to show is complete?

Comment: @JoseAvilez I am saying "The **class** of hypergeometric pdfs is complete", where the class is defined as $ \{ P_D : D =1,2,..., N\}$. We say a statistic T(X) is complete if its family of distributions is complete.

Comment: How do you define completeness for the class of hypergeometric distributions?

Comment: A family of distributions $\{P_D: D = 0,1,2,....,N \}$ is complete if for any measurable function $T$, $E_D[T(X)] = 0$ implies that $T$ is identically zero.

Comment: it seems your definition is missing a few quantifiers. What is $X$? This is also not a standard definition of completeness. Like I said, completeness is a property of a statistic for a parametric family: $T$ is complete for $\{P_\theta\}_{\theta}$ if $E_\theta (g(T)) = 0$ for all $\theta$ implies that $g = 0$ almost surely. If your $X$ is simply a draw from the distribution, then you are saying that $T(X) = X$ is a complete statistic.

Comment: X is a random variable that has hypergeometric distribution. The textbook used in my class is [An Introduction to Statistics](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/7344_2018-12-2-10-44-10.pdf), and this is how they define completeness. The definition for a complete family of PDFs is on page 364.